# Java problem-Whats the reason behind and what will be probable output

Tags: java

1.)

```
long milli=24*60*60*1000;
long micro=24*60*60*1000*1000;
long result=micro/milli;
```

The result should be `1000` but it's not.

Please can you tell me the output and explain it?

2)

```
int i=0;
for(a=0;a<=integer.MAX_VAL;a++)
{
    i++;
}

S.O.P(i);
```

Normally it went to infine loop why because there is max value it should come out of loop. At what conditions it will executed sucessfully and what will be excepted value. .....Anyone can tell me about VM...  handing of nummbers in JAVA

Comment: Your second question does not make sense. Maybe you should complete it?

Comment: @Rakesh: if this is homework, please follow the [guidelines for asking homework questions on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). As for the sample code in question 2, make sure it's [representative of the original source](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: This question is extremely difficult to understand. Please consider revising it, and adding the homework tag if appropriate.

Comment: @Rakesh unless people are avidly following your question, they are unlikely to see your new change "Anyone can tell me about VM... handing of nummbers in JAVA" - I suggest creating a new, well-formatted question which asks this new question clearly.

Comment: Different (and unrelated) questions should be separate questions on this site.

Answer (score 5):

You need to put an `L` in there for long-conversion

```
long micro=24*60*60*1000*1000L
```

Comment: This is surely wrong? It's long micro  = 24 *60 * 60 *1000*1000L that needs the forced long conversion.

Comment: Absolutely, I was hoping that to be inferred!

Comment: @Erik - because you're the only person who's noticed it's wrong?

Comment: Erik...its small mistake i typed wrong second question .it executed and give the value, here someone asked question when it will not execute regarding Integer.Max_value at what codition ....Its some VM concept but i didn't find it

Answer (score 2):

2)

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] ar){
        int i=0;
        for(int a=0; a< Integer.MAX_VALUE;a++) {
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

output:

**2147483647**

Comment: Notice: you're using `<` comparison, while the question puts `<=`

Answer (score 1):

This feels jeopardy, having to guess the question as well as the answer. ;)

I think the second question should read

```
int i=0;
for(a=0;a<=Integer.MAX_VALUE;a++)
    i++
```

This will go into an infinite loop because all possible values of `a` are <= MAX_VALUE.

You can re-write this loop as

```
int a=0;
do {
    i++
} while (a++ != Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

`i` will be Integer.MIN_VALUE as it overflows.

Comment: the condition is only <Integer.MAX_VALUE not <=.

Comment: Actually the condition is `a<integer.MAX_VAL`, anything else is subjective. ;) The OP is expecting to get an infinite loop so I suspect this is just one of the bugs in his/her code.

Comment: If it's jeopardy just send the question to watson!

Comment: @Peter Lawrey and extraneon, yeah according to his description it should have been this code.

Comment: I am waiting from the pocket edition of *Watson* , won't be long.

Comment: @GK, when the OP posted the question again it had `<=` ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041634/why-is-this-an-infinite-loop