# Why does this not result in 1000?

Tags: java, numbers, int, long-integer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java problem-Whats the reason behind and what will be probable output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039093/java-problem-whats-the-reason-behind-and-what-will-be-probable-output)

```
long milli=24*60*60*1000;
long micro=24*60*60*1000*1000;
long result=micro/milli;
```

The result should be 1000 but its not. Why does it work when I use `24*60*60*1000*1000L`?

Can someone tell me the reason for this?

Comment: What result are you getting instead?

Comment: [Repost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039093/java-problem-whats-the-reason-behind-and-what-will-be-probable-output/5039121#5039121) of your previous question today which also happens to contain the answer.

Comment: you are going out of int range, need to tell VM to use long.

Comment: This question is too easy, there were four more answers while I typed mine ...

Comment: @Paulo, There were answer to the first post as well. ;)

Comment: I feel this is slightly my fault. Rakesh added a new question to his original post in the form of an edit - "Anyone can tell me about VM... handing of nummbers in JAVA" - I told him that if he wanted that question to be noticed, he should ask a new question. Either I wasn't clear ot he didn't understand :S

Comment: @Rich - thanks! I've edited the post to be able to removed my -1 (and did so).

Answer (score 8):

The trouble is that the calculation is done on `int`s and then casted to `long`, and unfortunately 24*60*60*1000*1000 won't fit in an `int` and wraps around. You could do something like

```
long micro=24L*60*60*1000*1000;
```

to force the last multiplication to be done on longs.

Comment: To add to this (correct) answer: since all the terms on the right hand side are ints, the arithmetic, including overflow, will be done on ints. The result will then be converted to long. By adding an 'L' or a (long) on the right hand side you force a widening conversion of all integers to long (before it overflows) and the result won't overflow.

Answer (score 6):

Easy, if you know, but always a surprise ;)

The literal `1000` is an `int` value, so the multiplaction is done with integers and **not** with longs.

```
long micro=24*60*60*1000*1000;
```

is interpreted like

```
long micro = (long) ((int) 24*60*60*1000*1000);
```

which is `500654080` instead of `86400000000`

Use at least one long literal in your expression, this forces the whole calculation to be done in `long`:

```
long milli=24*60*60*1000;
long micro=24*60*60*1000*1000 * 1L; // forces a calculation in long
long result=micro/milli;
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be that `24*60*60*1000*1000` is treated as an int and is getting truncated.

To force it to be treated as a long, make one (or all) of the numbers a long by suffixing it with `L`:

```
24L*60L*60L*1000L*1000L
```

Answer (score 1):

When you tell Java to multiply `int` values (and whole number literals are always of type `int` unless you append `l` or `L`), then the result will **always** be of type `int` as well. `24*60*60*1000*1000` results in an overflow, because it's bigger than the biggest possible `int` value (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`).

Then (after the overflow was "resolved" by cutting of the most significant bits), the value gets assigned to a `long` value.

Specifying one of the numbers as `long` (`1000L`) means that the **whole** multiplication is done with `long` numbers.

Comment: joachim thankx for help....there is same question  2)
int i=0;
for(a=0;a<=integer.MAX_VAL;a++)
{
i++;
}

S.O.P(i);


Normally it went to infine loop why because there is max value it should come out of loop. At what conditions it will executed sucessfully and wht will be excepted value.


plz help me ...its said both problems are relates to same concept...I am unable to find help me

Comment: @Rakesh: please ask that as a separate question, comments are not really the correct place for this kind of discussions.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that the `int` datatype only supports numbers until around 2000000000, while your number is 86400000000, which is about 40 times this number. Thus your multiplication wraps around (discards the highest bits of the result).

So you need to switch to the next larger datatype, `long`, by telling Java that at least one of your numbers are intended as such:

```
 long micro=24*60*60*1000*1000L;
```

Then your result will be right.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're doing integer (32 bits) arythmetics, and then transform the int result into a long. SInce the numbers are too big, it doesn't work.

Replace by :

```
long milli=24*60*60*1000L;
long micro=24*60*60*1000*1000L;
long result=micro/milli;
```

to force the operations do be done with longs.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value and int can hold is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and your macro value is bigger than an integer can hold and calculation is made on integers so it is being truncated.  If you make one of the multipliers long (ending with L or l) it will calculate correctly.

```
long milli=24*60*60*1000;
long micro=24*60*60*1000*1000L;
long result=micro/milli;
```