# SimpleDateFormat always returns 1970.01.17 with wrong timezone

Tags: java, date, processing, simpledateformat, epoch

I have been using Processing 3.0, and I am trying to print a simple timestamp when my Arduino outputs certain values, but it is not working. I tried to use SimpleDateFormat, but it always returns `1970.01.17 17:48:35 GMT`, rather than the actual time. Below is the MVCE:

```
void setup ()
{      
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss z");
  format.setTimeZone (TimeZone.getDefault());

  long timestamp = getTimeNow();
  println(format.format(new Date(timestamp)));
  println(timestamp);
}

long getTimeNow ()
{
   Date d = new Date ();
   Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

   long current = d.getTime()/1000;
   long timezone = cal.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET)/1000;
   long daylight = cal.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET)/1000;
   return current + timezone + daylight;
}
```

Output example:

```
1970.01.17 17:48:35 GMT 
1442915733
```

I doubt the issue is with `getTimeNow()`, since, if I plug the values into an online epoch converter I get the correct time. What is the issue in the above code?

Comment: Can you point us to the doc for `format(long)`? AFAIK this doesn't exist

Comment: True, it doesn't exist. Should've checked the reference more thoroughly. Still, if I try to convert it to a date, using the Date constructor, it still gives me the wrong issue. Edited the post to reflect the change.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `Date` object parameter accepts the time as long in milliseconds, not seconds. You need to multiply it by 1000. and make sure that you supply it as long.

```
Date dateObj = new Date(1442915733L * 1000);
System.out.println(dateObj);
```

Comment: Ok, it almost works, has the correct timezone and all... but it has the wrong DST offset, so it shows the time one hour early.

Comment: `/1000` still there? they should simply be removed. Otherwise long integer division truncates. Though that should be okay.

Comment: Put 1000L instead of 1000. More informations here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5041249/2612536

Comment: You are my hero! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Decided to post this as an answer, since it's different from Mitesh's solution.

I dropped the `getTimeNow()` function and instead I simply created a new date and used that:

```
void setup ()
{      
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss z");
  format.setTimeZone (TimeZone.getDefault());

  Date timestamp = new Date ();
  println(format.format(timestamp));
}
```

The reason is two fold. I had another issue with the code, after applying Matesh's answer, where the TimeZone would disregard the DST settings, so the hour in the timestamp was wrong. Furthermore, this solution removed the need for several lines of code, which is always helpful.