# long timestamp to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, java-8, timestamp, java-time

I have a long timestamp 1499070300 (equivalent to Mon, 03 Jul 2017 16:25:00 +0800) but when I convert it to LocalDateTime I get 1970-01-18T16:24:30.300

Here's my code

```
long test_timestamp = 1499070300;

LocalDateTime triggerTime =
                LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(test_timestamp), TimeZone
                        .getDefault().toZoneId());
```

Comment: long test_timestamp = 1499070300l;??

Comment: Use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` instead of `TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId()`

Comment: You’re not the first to ask a about a bug like this one. For example: [SimpleDateFormat always returns 1970.01.17 with wrong timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712735/simpledateformat-always-returns-1970-01-17-with-wrong-timezone#32712906).

Comment: Similar: [*Converting 19-digit Unix Timestamp to a Readable Date*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56277090/642706)

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You need to pass timestamp in milliseconds:

```
long test_timestamp = 1499070300000L;
LocalDateTime triggerTime =
        LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(test_timestamp), 
                                TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId());  

System.out.println(triggerTime);
```

Result:

```
2017-07-03T10:25
```

Or use `ofEpochSecond` instead:

```
long test_timestamp = 1499070300L;
LocalDateTime triggerTime =
       LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(test_timestamp),
                               TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId());   

System.out.println(triggerTime);
```

Result:

```
2017-07-03T10:25
```

Comment: BTW if you are using AndroidThreeTen, replace `TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId()` with `DateTimeUtils.toZoneId(TimeZone.getDefault())`.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using the Android threeten back port then the line you want is this

```
LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(startTime), ZoneId.systemDefault())
```

Answer (score 6):

Try with the following..

```
long test_timestamp = 1499070300000L;
    LocalDateTime triggerTime =
            LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(test_timestamp), TimeZone
                    .getDefault().toZoneId());
```

By default `1499070300000` is int if it dosen't contain l in end.Also pass time in milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that the timestamp is not in milliseconds but expressed in seconds from the Epoch date. Either multiply by 1000 your timestamp or use the `Instant.ofEpochSecond()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`Instant.ofEpochMilli()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli-long-) or `Instant.ofEpochSecond()` method with it-

```
long test_timestamp = 1499070300L;
LocalDateTime date =
    LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(test_timestamp ), TimeZone
        .getDefault().toZoneId());
```

Comment: You mean "Try with Instant.ofEpochSecond()", right? Otherwise your text is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

SIMPLE and straight forward solution will **(KOTLIN)**

```
            val timeStamp:Long=559585985988
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a - MMM dd,yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
            val tz = TimeZone.getDefault()
            val now = Date()
            val offsetFromUtc = tz.getOffset(now.time)
            val localeTimeStr = sdf.format(timeStamp + offsetFromUtc) //add the offset to get the local time from the epoch timestamp
```