# Java Converting 19-digit Unix Timestamp to a Readable Date

Tags: java, unix-timestamp, datetime-conversion

I am trying to convert 19 digit Unix timestamp such as `1558439504711000000` (one and a half [quintillion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers)) into a readable date/time format. My timestamp ends with 6 zeros which suggests the time is in nano seconds.

I have come across some examples where people have used time zones which I don't need. Another example uses ofEpochSecond like so:

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(seconds, nanos);
```

But I am not sure whether I need to use ofEpochSecond.

The code below gives my most recent approach of achieving this:

```
String timeStamp = "1558439504711000000";
long unixNanoSeconds = Long.parseLong(timeStamp);
Date date = new java.util.Date(timeStamp*1000L); 
// My preferred date format
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");                    
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println("The timestamp in your preferred format is: " +  formattedDate);
```

But the output I get is something like this:

```
// The timestamp in your preferred format is: 11-12-49386951 11:43:20
```

Which does not show the year format in e.g. 2019 format.

Comment: Any reason you are using `Date` over `LocalDate`?

Comment: Why do you multiply by 1000?

Comment: No specific reason, just saw in an example.

Comment: The code in the post doesn't compile. Did you forget to add a quote?

Comment: Sorry, missed the semicolon, and the quotes, for the timestamp variable.

Comment: Still, I think you can't assign a number to a string.

Comment: (if there's a type named `string` in java at all)

Comment: There is one with a uppercase 'S' :-D

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it will still not compile. Try it yourself at a compiler......

Comment: Same as  Thorbjørn : if you multiply nanoseconds by 1000, you get pico seconds. `new Date(long)` does not take pico seconds as its input as I recall, rather, milliseconds (check the javadoc). So, in short, divide rather than multiply ? (Or cleaner yet use `TimeUnit.convert` / TimeUnit.toMillis).

Comment: Dividing also gives `25-12-51354 06:25:11`, not a proper year.

Comment: @MarkB : by 1_000_000 actually (made the same mistake myself, confusing millis and micros).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using this

```
Date date = new java.util.Date(timeStamp/1000000);
```

Instead of multiplying by **1000**, divide by **1000000**

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

Never use legacy class `java.util.Date`. Instead, use modern [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant                                  // The modern way to represent a moment in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds. Supplants the terrible `java.util.Date` class.
.ofEpochSecond(                          // Parse a count since epoch reference of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
    0L ,                                 // Passing zero for the count of whole seconds, to let the class determine this number from the 2nd argument.
    Long.parse( "1558439504711000000" )  // Count of nanoseconds since the epoch reference of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. 
)                                        // Returns a `Instant` object.
.atZone(                                 // Adjust from UTC to the wall-clock time used by the people of a specific region (a time zone).
    ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ) 
)                                        // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object. Same moment as the `Instant`, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
.format(                                 // Generate text to communicate the value of the moment as seen through this time zone.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(         // Define how to format our generated text.
        "dd-MM-uuuu HH:mm:ss" ,          // Specify your desired formatting pattern.
        Locale.UK                        // Pass a `Locale` to be used in localizing, to (a) determine human language used in translating name of day-of-week and such, and (b) determine cultural norms to decide issues of capitalization, abbreviation, etc. Not really needed for this particular formatting pattern, but a good habit to specify `Locale`.
    )                                    // Returns a `DateTimeFormatter` object.
)                                        // Returns a `String` object containing our text.
```

> 21-05-2019 12:51:44

…or…

```
Instant
.ofEpochSecond (
    TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds( 
       Long.parse( "1558439504711000000" ) 
    ) ,
    ( 1_558_439_504_711_000_000L % 1_000_000_000L )
)
.toString()
```

> 2019-05-21T11:51:44.711Z

Note the hour difference because the time zone is one hour ahead of UTC.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The `java.util.Date` class is *terrible*. Along with its littermates such as `Calendar` & `SimpleDateFormat`, they amount to a awful mess. Avoid them. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community gave up on them when they adopted JSR 310.

## `Instant`

A `java.util.Date` object represents a moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), with a resolution of [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond). Its replacement is [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html), also a moment in UTC but with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). Internally, both track a count since the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) of [first moment of 1970 in UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

To avoid dealing with gigantic numbers, internally a `Instant` tracks a number of whole seconds since 1970 *plus* a fractional second kept as a number of nanoseconds. Two separate numbers. Those are what you need to feed [`Instant.ofEpochSecond`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond(long,long)).

Parse your input string as a `long` using the [`Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html) class. By the way, notice that your value is pushing towards to [the limit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE) of a [64-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing) integer.

```
long totalNanos = Long.parse( "1558439504711000000" ) ;
```

Use the [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) to do the math of splitting out whole seconds.

```
long secondsPortion = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds( totalNanos ) ;
```

[Modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) by a billion, the remainder being the nanoseconds of the fractional second.

```
long nanosPortion = ( totalNanos % 1_000_000_000L ) ;
```

Instantiate an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( secondsPortion , nanosPortion ) ;
```

> My timestamp ends with 6 zeros which suggests the time is in nano seconds.

Actually, nanoseconds count up to a billion, so nine (9) digits not six (6). The fractional second in your count from epoch is `711000000`, or 711,000,000 nanos. Your number of whole seconds is `1558439504`, or 1,558,439,504 (one and a half billion). As a decimal:

1,558,439,504.711000000 seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z

### Time Zone

> I have come across some examples where people have used time zones which I don't need.

To represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline, **you *always* need a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone)** (or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of hours-minutes-seconds).

To see that same moment through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone), apply a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `BST` or `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;  // Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
```

> 2019-05-21T12:51:44.711+01:00[Europe/London]

Notice the adjustment in the time-of-day, going from hour 11 to hour 12. This makes sense as `Europe/London` zone is an hour ahead of UTC on that date. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

## Shortcut

As Ole V.V. noted in the comment, you could skip the math discussed above. Feed the entire number of nanoseconds as the second argument to `ofEpochSecond`. The class internally does the math to separate whole seconds from the fractional second.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( 0L , 1_558_439_504_711_000_000L ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com.](https://ideone.com/uUnJOT)

## Generate text

Generate text representing the value of that `ZonedDateTime` in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format extended to append the name of the time zone in square brackets.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;
```

> 2019-05-21T12:51:44.711+01:00[Europe/London]

Or let *java.time* automatically localize for you.

```
Locale locale = Locale.UK;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( locale );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

> 21/05/2019, 12:51

Or specify a custom format.

```
Locale locale = Locale.UK;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu HH:mm:ss" , locale ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

> 21-05-2019 12:51:44

Tip: Be very careful about providing a date-time without specifying the zone explicitly. This creates ambiguity, where the user may assume a different zone/offset is in play.

Comment: How do I format the date then and output as a string? I am currently getting the date in this format `Tue May 21 12:51:44 BST 2019` with `Date myDate = Date.from(instant);`

Comment: @mrT In what time zone?

Comment: In BST time zone

Comment: @mrT There is [no such time zone as `BST`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Do you mean `Europe/London`?

Comment: Yes, That’s what I meant.

Comment: Perfect! That is exactly what I wanted :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing wrong with that, you are dealing with a timestamp that represent a date in the FUTURE (a really far away date in the future).

If you consider this:

`String timeStamp = "1558439504";`

this should give you: 05/21/2019 @ 11:51am (UTC)

Then there is I think an easy way to get the Date. Just create the Instant first based on that timestamp and then do:

```
Date myDate = Date.from(instant);
```