# How to Parse Milliseconds to Time with String Easily

Tags: android

I need to parse milliseconds data that I recieve from Json as :

trackTimeMillis : 39045834  -> x hour/hours - y minute/minutes or  y minute/minutes - z second/seconds

I put slash symbols because it has to change according to plural form.
I write something like that but didn't like it and probably has some mistakes in it. How can I do it better and easy (understandable)

Here is the code :

```
@BindingAdapter("trackTime")
fun setDate(view: TextView, milliseconds: Int){
    var parsedText : String = ""
    if(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliseconds.toLong()) > 1){ // if hour >1

        if(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds.toLong()) > 1){ // if hour >1 and minutes >1
            parsedText = String.format("%d Hours, %d Minutes",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliseconds.toLong()),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds.toLong()) - (60 * TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliseconds.toLong())))

        } else if(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds.toLong()) < 1){ // if hour >1 and minutes == 0
            parsedText = String.format("%d Hours",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds.toLong()))
        } 

    } else if (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliseconds.toLong()) < 1){ // if hour == 0

        if(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds.toLong()) > 1){ // if hour==0 and minutes >1
            parsedText = String.format( "%d Minutes, %d Seconds",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds.toLong()),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(milliseconds.toLong()) - (60 * TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds.toLong())))


        } else if(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds.toLong()) < 1){ // if hour==0 and minutes < 0
            parsedText = String.format( "%d Seconds",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(milliseconds.toLong()))
        }

    } else { // if hour == 1
        if(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds.toLong()) > 1){ // if hour == 1 and minutes >1

            parsedText = String.format("%d Hour, %d Minutes",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliseconds.toLong()),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds.toLong()) - (60 * TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliseconds.toLong())))

        } else if(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds.toLong()) < 1){ // if hour  == 1 and minutes == 0

            parsedText = String.format("%d Hour",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliseconds.toLong()))
        }
    }

    view.text = parsedText
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [long timestamp to LocalDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44883432/long-timestamp-to-localdatetime)

Comment: @leonardkraemer It would do same thing what I do with string format but I still need to control if singular or plural