# Why is this an infinite loop?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java problem-Whats the reason behind and what will be probable output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039093/java-problem-whats-the-reason-behind-and-what-will-be-probable-output)

```
int i=0;
for(a=0;a<=integer.MAX_VAL;a++)
{
  i++;
}

System.out.println(i);
```

Why does this result in an infite loop?

Comment: Repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039093/java-problem-whats-the-reason-behind-and-what-will-be-probable-output already answered.

Comment: @Peter - yes, but someone (Rich) advised him to do so. Agree to closing but not to downvoting.

Comment: I already guessed this was the real question and answered it as well as how to fix it so it doesn't go into an infinite loop.  The poster should have made it clear this was a repost and why this was a different question or what further detail they were look for. There have been 13 answers to 2 questions but only one comment in reply.

Answer (score 6):

Every possible integer is `<= Integer.MAX_VALUE`.
The condition in your `for` loop can *never* be `false`.

When `a` reaches `MAX_VALUE`, `a + 1` will overflow and wrap around into `MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int a = 0; a <= Integer.MAX_VALUE; a++)
```

Once `a` is equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, you increment it again, which is an overflow. The exit condition (`a` is bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) will never occur:

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 = -2147483648
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the condition to LESS THAN and then the loop should do exactly Integer.MAX_VAL iterations.

```
int i=0;
for(a=0;a<integer.MAX_VAL;a++)
{
i++;
}

S.O.P(i);
```